# Trying to write a jQuery plugin but I don't know how to call a method from init

Tags: jquery

## jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bg9vL/

Console output:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'each'

```
 var methods = {

    init: function (options) {

        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend({
            'maxWidth': 0,
            'maxHeight': 0,
            'forceAspect': true
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            // if max size wasn't specified, position only
            var nosize = settings.maxWidth === 0 || settings.maxHeight === 0;
            var container = $(this).parent();

            $(this).css('position', 'relative');

            // fit when window is resized
            $(window).bind('resize.tailorfit', methods.fit);

            // fit when page has loaded
            $(window).bind('load.tailorfit', methods.fit);

            // fit on initial load
            methods.fit.apply();
        });

    }, ...
```

Comment: Yes it is! It's in the js section.

Comment: Oops, sorry. But I'm not getting the error you specified. Just getting a 403 on the imgur image.

Comment: That's strange... it's a good link.

Comment: imgur doesn't allow hotlinking I think; the image must be cached in your browser. Try a different browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that you need to wrap that this with a jQuery marker.

```
...
$(this).each(
...
```

It doesn't recognize it as a jQuery object, so the function each isn't available to it.

You do have a container issue after that which you should be able to easily solve.

Comment: No, the object passed to a plugin function IS a jQuery object, not a DOM element / Array.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out how to use options defined in init in the other functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
methods.fit.apply();
```

calls `fit` with the global object as this, which has no method `each`

now, you can technically fix this by doing `$(this)` in the function `fit`, but I'm not sure this is what you wanted to do.

also note that your jsFiddle doesn't execute the callback given to `$('.image-container > img').load`